# sending anonymous type to IronPython from C# throws MissingMemberException

Tags: c#, ironpython, anonymous-types

The below code throws a 'MissingMemberException'

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptRuntime runtime = engine.Runtime;
ScriptScope scope = runtime.CreateScope();

string code = "emp.Name==\"Bernie\"";

ScriptSource source =
  engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Expression);

var emp = new {Name = "Bernie"};

scope.SetVariable("emp", emp);

var res = (double)source.Execute(scope);
```

if I declare a type called 'Employee' and give it a member 'Name', and use this instead:

```
var emp = new Employee {Name = "Bernie"}
```

It works just as expected. Does anyone know why it doesn't work on anonymous types and is there a workaround?

Comment: Is the `Employee` class public or internal?

Comment: Employee class is public (but it works just fine using Employee class)

Comment: What happens if you change the employee class to be internal? Does it have the same behavior as the anonymous type? (Anonymous types are always internal, so I am wondering if that is the problem).

Comment: I did find that if the class was not public, the issue happened there too. But I didn't include that in my question as I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that anonymous types are internal. When the complier generates an anonymous type, it is approximately this:

```
internal class <>f__AnonymousType0`1'<'<Name>j__TPar'> //or whatever silly name the compiler uses
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You can replicate the error you are getting with a concrete class by changing it to be internal:

```
internal class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

OK, so that's why it's happening. How do you fix it? Well, the best approach is to just use a concrete class that is public like you have already found.

Comment: I did find that if the class was not public, the issue happened there too. But I didn't include that in my question as I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. thanks